# In VS Code, why does a maximized panel over a notebook editor get obscured by the notebook editor's toolbar?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

It only happens when I have a Jupyter notebook open. When I switch to the terminal panel and maximize it, it maximizes all the way but there is a narrow window that it doesn't cover at the top. I've attached a photo for reference.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX2GX.png)

Any idea why this is happening?

I've tested this with ordinary python files open or with no files open and the terminal window goes full-screen just fine.

I tried different orientations in the "customize layout panel" settings, like "justified", "zen mode", but none of them worked because this problem seems very specific to when an ipynb file is open.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. The fix is scheduled to be made and released in the 1.86 release (end of January 2024). See the following issue tickets:

- [Integrated terminal maximized panel glitch with jupyter notebook #179671](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179671)
- [Jupyter notebook toolbar on top of maximized panel
  #179700](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179700)

Wait patiently for the fix to come. The fix is made by PR [don't layout notebook when not visible #202392](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/202392).

The cause is described in this comment:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179671#issuecomment-1751176589 (TL;DR grid views and z-index fun).